# How to transform/map JSON data into different model

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to transform some data. It's an array of objects, with each object containing an array of items, each item being a unique combination of color and size.

```
[
    {
        "style": "styleName_01",
        "someOtherKey": "",
        "skus": [
            { "sku": "001", "color": "COLOR_01", "size": "SIZE_08" },
            { "sku": "002", "color": "COLOR_02", "size": "SIZE_07" },
            { "sku": "003", "color": "COLOR_02", "size": "SIZE_08" },
            { "sku": "004", "color": "COLOR_02", "size": "SIZE_12" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "style": "styleName_02",
        "someOtherKey": "",
        "skus": [
            { "sku": "005", "color": "COLOR_01", "size": "SIZE_05" },
            { "sku": "006", "color": "COLOR_03", "size": "SIZE_07" },
            { "sku": "007", "color": "COLOR_03", "size": "SIZE_08" },
            { "sku": "008", "color": "COLOR_02", "size": "SIZE_04" }
        ]
    }
]
```

The product is selected first by color, which filters to sizes available in the color, so I'm trying to get each color that occurs in my skus loop and then find all the items with sizes that occur in that color, i.e.,

```
[
    {
        "style": "",
        "someOtherKey": "",
        "sku": "001",
        "color": "COLOR_01",
        "sizes": [ "SIZE_08", "SIZE_05" ]
    },
    {
        "style": "",
        "someOtherKey": "",
        "sku": "002",
        "color": "COLOR_02",
        "sizes": [ "SIZE_07", "SIZE_08", "SIZE_12", "SIZE_04"  ]
    },
    {
        "style": "",
        "someOtherKey": "",
        "sku": "003",
        "color": "COLOR_03",
        "sizes": [ "SIZE_07", "SIZE_08" ]
    }
]
```

I'm able to build the sku objects but I need some guidance as to how to get only the (unique) size values where I need them:

```
let newSkus = []

let newSku = {
    "sku": "",
    "color": "",
    "sizes": []
}

for (style of data) { // for each style object ...
    let numSkus = style.skus.length;

    for (let sku = numSkus - 1; sku >= 0; sku--) { // for each item in items[]

        if (newSku.color !== `${style.skus[sku].color}`) {
            newSku.color = `${style.skus[sku].color}`;
            newSku.sizes.push(`${style.skus[sku].frameSize}`);
        }
        else {}

        console.log("newSku", newSku); // wrong; getting all sizes from all items
```

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Whiskey T.

Comment: I think a problem in your approach is, that all colors use the same `newSku` variable and thus append to the same `sizes` array. If you would use one object per color it would probably work

Comment: edited to clarify that other keys in the orig data model are in fact also required (A_A noted below: "as we don't care to which style name they belong", because I had not clarified that

Comment: I'm not sure what your desired outcome would be like this, in particular how you want the other information in the result. For instance, COLOR_01 is in both, styleName_01 and styleName_02. Should the result now have an array `styles: [styleName_01, styleName_02]`? If not, what else?

Comment: Thx A_A. In the desired result there are indeed style names common to multiple SKUs as they're actually referring to a style *group*. I realize I've done a bad job of describing this problem. The goal result is like this:
[
{ // style obj
"styleCode": "(not unique)",
"collectionName": "(not unique)",
"collectionID": "(not unique)",
"colors": [
{
"name": "BLACK",
"UPCs": [
{
"upc": "123",
"size": "01",
"weight": "",
"price": 3.99
},
{
"upc": "246",
"size": "02",
"weight": "",
"price": 3.99
}
] // UPCs
} // color
] // colors
}
]

cheers

Answer (score 1):

I would split it up into multiple steps:

1. create array of all skus (as we don't care to which style name they belong)
2. group it by color (and join the sizes to a single array)
3. convert it to your desired format

You can see the output of each step in the console:

```js
const data = [
    {
        "style": "styleName_01",
        "skus": [
            { "sku": "001", "color": "COLOR_01", "size": "SIZE_08" },
            { "sku": "002", "color": "COLOR_02", "size": "SIZE_07" },
            { "sku": "003", "color": "COLOR_02", "size": "SIZE_08" },
            { "sku": "004", "color": "COLOR_02", "size": "SIZE_12" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "style": "styleName_02",
        "skus": [
            { "sku": "005", "color": "COLOR_01", "size": "SIZE_05" },
            { "sku": "006", "color": "COLOR_03", "size": "SIZE_07" },
            { "sku": "007", "color": "COLOR_03", "size": "SIZE_08" },
            { "sku": "008", "color": "COLOR_02", "size": "SIZE_04" }
        ]
    }
]

// flatten into an array of skus
const skus = data.flatMap(style => style.skus)
console.log('skus', skus)

// group by color
const colorsObj = skus.reduce((colors, sku) => {
  if (!colors.hasOwnProperty(sku.color))
    colors[sku.color] = [] // use Set if you want unique values
  colors[sku.color].push(sku.size)
  return colors
}, {})
console.log('colorsObj', colorsObj)

// create array from object entries
const colorsArr = Object.entries(colorsObj).map(([color, sizes], i) => {
  return {
    sku: i,
    color,
    sizes
  }
})
console.log('colorsArr', colorsArr)
```

Comment: Thanks A_A. I'm stuck on how best to include in the skus array the other keys & values from the given data model. I thought I could use .map but this would get pretty gnarly and a lot of looping for 8-9 keys ... can you please sugg how to do this where you're first mapping the data.skus?